# SQL query remove only some of the duplicated rows in the results of a join

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

```
CREATE TABLE `rule` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `duplicate_mode` char(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `rule` (`id`, `duplicate_mode`) VALUES
(1, 'single'),
(2, 'multiple');

CREATE TABLE `rule_tag` (
  `rule_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `rule_id` (`rule_id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `rule_tag_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES `rule` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `rule_tag_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `rule_tag` (`rule_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(2, 4);

CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `tag` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'foo'),
(2, 'bar'),
(3, 'bar'),
(4, 'baz');
```

Table visualization:

```
rule:
| id | duplicate_mode
| 1  | single
| 2  | multiple

rule_tag:
| rule_id | tag_id
| 1       | 1
| 1       | 2
| 2       | 3
| 2       | 4

tag:
| id | name  
| 1  | Foo   
| 2  | Bar   
| 3  | Baz   
| 4  | Bar
```

Wanted results (Note, the tag name that matches doesn't matter)

```
| rule_id | duplicate_mode | name
| 1       | single         | foo
| 2       | multiple       | bar
| 2       | multiple       | baz
```

The duplicate mode column is supposed to define whether the rule is duplicated in the results

A `SELECT DISTINCT` with left joins would remove all duplicates, so is not a valid option.

If this is possible with a subquery, I have no idea how.

An `UNION` doing two separate queries, one for the single mode with a `DISTINCT` and another for the multiple mode without would solve it, but is there a way to do it in a single query?

I think it's also possible to do 2 joins with subqueries, but that's probably worse than `UNION`

Comment: Please define what you mean by "duplicate" in your case. "foo" and "bar" are distinct values, but you only have "foo" for rule_id=1 in your "Wanted result". Why is it "foo" and not "bar" or both?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Because the tag name that matches doesn't matter, I just want the rule 1 to only be once in the results. I'll edit with a clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation:

```
select r.id, r.duplicate_mode, max(t.name) as name
from rule r join
     rule_tag rt
     on rt.rule_id = r.id join
     tag t
     on rt.tag_id = t.id
group by r.id, r.duplicate_mode, (case when r.duplicate_mode = 'multiple' then t.id end);
```

Or filtering:

```
select r.id, r.duplicate_mode, max(t.name) as name
from rule r join
     rule_tag rt
     on rt.rule_id = r.id join
     tag t
     on rt.tag_id = t.id
where r.duplicate_mode = 'multiple' or
      rt.tag_id = (select min(rt2.tag_id)
                   from rule_tag rt2 
                   where rt.rule_id = rt.rule_id
                  );
```

Comment: I like your aggregation solution a lot, although I'm having problems wrapping my head around how a CASE works in a GROUP BY.

Comment: @Alex . . . A `CASE` just creates another column that can be used for aggregation.

Comment: No, I see that, what had problems was the concept of the column being added only some rows. But doing an explain I see that it just creates a temporal table. For some reason my initial idea was that it was doing the group by at a row level.

Answer (score 0):

Could be using union all between distinct and not distinct  query for single and multiple

```
Select  distinct rt.rule_id,  r.duplicate_mode, t.name 
from rule_tag rt 
inner join  rule r on r.id = rt.rule_id and duplicate_mode = 'single'
inner join tag t on t.id= rt.tag_id 

UNION ALL 

select  rt.rule_id,  r.duplicate_mode, t.name 
from rule_tag rt 
inner join  rule r on r.id = rt.rule_id and duplicate_mode = 'multiple'
inner join tag t on t.id= rt.tag_id
```

Comment: _An UNION doing two separate queries, one for the single mode with a DISTINCT and another for the multiple mode without would solve it, but is there a way to do it in a single query?_


I know `UNION` works, but I was wondering if there's a better solution that only involves one query.

Comment: tecnically a UNION is a single query  ..  anyway  .. this is what a can suggest  .. (SO is not  a coding service .. " a  la carte .."  but an question/answer  site  .. so you request seems a bit  .. strange  ..

Comment: You're right that UNION is a single query, I should have explained myself better. Rereading the title, I see how the request is confusing, I'm not asking for a solution in code, just what other alternatives there are that i didn't know about, like using aggregation with a CASE in a GROUP BY.